# How to boot STM32F405RGT6 with DFU

Tags: stm32, boot, usb-otg, cubemx, dfu

I have designed and assembled a PCB. All connections are fine and leds are blinking when i open the CUBEMX. But I don't know what to do after this point. Do I need to put some drivers before using DFU?
If so, i don't have an ST-LINK Programmer how can i use the only input for this pcb (which is PB11,PB12 as AN2662 suggests). Its also interesting that device is responding to CubeMX . Does device has any code in it?

MCU :
STM32F405RGT6

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But i will try to answer to your question with my understanding from the question. First thing that you need to find the datasheet of mcu. Now, you can able to find related pins for programming. Using these pins, you can program your hw.

if you want to put dfu mode to your hw, Please check "Application Note 2606 STM32 microcontroller system memory boot mode".

Also, i wrote post about system memory bootloader, here is the link: https://engineeringvolkan.wordpress.com/2020/05/08/1928/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want to learn how to upload code into your uC. If you are not familiar with DFU, I suggest that you can use ST LINK V2. However, the important point is whether, or not you put output terminals for SW pins (SWDIO, NRST, SWCLK, SWO).

For the DFU, you should check Bootloader properties and bootloader configurations specifcally related to your uC. After these, you can watch this video [EEVBlog STM32 DFU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CDN8EQmOeo) and inspire from it.